# Error trying to load fixtures during Sylius Installation

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to use the web installer to load fixtures into my Sylius installation. It works fine if I don't check the load fixtures box but if it is checked, I get to this page:

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/installer/flow/sylius_installer/setup/forward
```

and get an error. I have tried it with 2 different versions of `fzaninotto/faker`

With `"fzaninotto/faker":                     "1.1.*",` in composer.json, I get:

```
Unknown formatter "randomFloat"
```

With `"fzaninotto/faker":                     "dev-master",` in composer.json, I get:

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in {webroot}\vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Provider\Base.php line 127
```

I have also tried running the installer in command prompt but I get a different error:

```
php app/console sylius:install --fixtures

[RuntimeException]
The "--fixtures" option does not exist.
```

I probably have that command wrong but that is how I have seen it in a couple of places.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I finally got it installed and posted what I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458978/how-do-i-install-sylius-on-bluehost-or-any-other-server-that-has-an-old-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run:

`php app/console sylius:install`

Installer will kindly ask you if you want to load fixtures.

Regarding error, did you installed vendors or updates?
It may be that new version of faker have BC break.

Comment: While running that install I get: 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Assetic\Util\PathUtils' not found in vendor\symfony\assetic-bundle
\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Command\DumpCommand.php on line 216. I'm going to try it again with version 2.3.x of assetic but last time that gave me different errors.

Comment: Idk what I did to mess it up but I redownloaded it again and installed it from the command line using the above command and it seems to work

Comment: php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load should also be a way to install fixtures

Comment: It is, now it should work, update code and install latest deps.

Answer (score 0):

This little array cast fixed things for me, as I think it's passing in an ArrayObject or "ArrayCollection"

```
$keys = array_keys((array)$array);
```

Maybe not the right solution but ...

Comment: The code here seems to be a better way to use the newer version of faker https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/216